# Best technique for learning specific area of c# with the plan of moving to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC as well as C#.  I'm familiar with Progress, and find the complexities of .Net to have it uses, but I probably won't need everything.

Over the last few months, I have been learning MVC and I've written several programs, but my technique has been top down- what do I need - ok let me learn how to do this.  While this has allowed me to make progress, I don't feel like I have a very solid understanding of C#.  With this concern I've spent some time attempting to learn c# without the focus of MVC.  What I've discovered is that most lessons have the goal of teaching you every abstract process rather than focusing on problems.  For example, I probably won't really have a need to use any of the graphical tools, the apps I'll be building will be more on the business side, so calculations, data manipulation, relating many tables to many tables.

My question is this.  Is there a way to learn C# out there that focuses on real-world business problems as a technique to teach the language or only this let throw everything out there and see if people can gather what they need.  I learn by doing, by having a problem and finding the solution, so most books are some what confusing for me or more to the point - boring.  For example - threading may be useful, but I don't know why I need to learn that before I learn how to import a csv file, run the parsed data through a few filters, and export the data to a new file.

I'd like an approach similar to how people learn a new language.  Rather than learn the structure of a language and all the rules, I want to learn as if I was thrown into a culture and heard the conversational most used aspects first.  I know I have rambled, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have a solid understanding of any language, you need to know about the language features and the syntax. Learning a language by focusing on real world problems is the next stage once you have a firm grip on the language itself which includes its features, syntax, the built in class libraries etc.

You wont come across many resources that teach you much by focusing on real world scenarios. To solve real world business problems, you need to be a good problem solver first and not a language master, mastery over a language does not make you a master at solving real world problems.

In my view, for you to get a firm grasp on the C# language, watch the free training videos of [Bob Tabor on Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/c-fundamentals-development-for-absolute-beginners#?fbid=-EKAsmgaWFY) . Once your done with it, then move on to the next series called [Programming in C# jump start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developer-training-with-programming-in-c#?fbid=-EKAsmgaWFY) which will explain the language in further detail with good examples. Watching these 2 video series are more than enough to give you a solid understanding of the C# language.

After that, you can move on to the asp.net mvc series, [Developing Asp.net mvc 4 web applications jump start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start#?fbid=-EKAsmgaWFY) that covers the basic asp.net mvc training. There is one more free video resource on Pluralsight that covers [asp.net mvc 3 in a little more detail by Scott Allen](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro&highlight=scott-allen_mvc3-building-infrastructure!scott-allen_mvc3-building-intro!scott-allen_mvc3-building-controllers!scott-allen_mvc3-building-security!scott-allen_mvc3-building-ajax!scott-allen_mvc3-building-deploy!scott-allen_mvc3-building-views!scott-allen_mvc3-building-data-ii!scott-allen_mvc3-building-tdd!scott-allen_mvc3-building-data-i-2#mvc3-building-infrastructure)

Solving real world problems involves many more aspects apart from the language, such as efficient algorithms, good design and architecture etc, so any programming language training you undergo will expose you to real world scenarios but on a very very small scale. Hope these resources help you out. Happy programming !

Comment: Thanks Neville,  I've been working with PluralSight as well as a few books from apress, I was just curious if there was some creative approach that I hadn't heard of.  Guess I'll stick with the tried and true.  Have a good one.

Comment: Neville, I just wanted to give you further thanks.  The Bob Tabor series so far seems to really go with my style of learning - feeling in a few holes that I had, had.  Thanks again.

Comment: filling*         this needed to be longer.